# How to remove blank spaces of treeview in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

[image]

In above diagram the name 'sebin joseph' is in a treeview.

Make treeview ShowLines property to `false`.

How to remove left side space from treeview as in the above diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the left side space by setting [ShowRootLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.showrootlines(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false`.

But note that it will also remove the plus/minus from the root nodes, so the only way to expand/collapse them would be the double click or using keyboard.

Comment: For me, that still leaves space

Answer (score 0):

It is the Property [Indent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.indent(v=vs.110).aspx) that you want to change:

```
treeView1.Indent = 5;
```

Also, [ShowPlusMinus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.showplusminus(v=vs.110).aspx) takes some of the space, if you want you can remove it:

```
treeView1.ShowPlusMinus = false;
```