# Windows Forms: Remove empty space left of treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview that I want to make as minimalist as possible.

```
        TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
        treeView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        treeView.Margin = new Padding(0);
        treeView.CheckBoxes = true;
```

[image: Default]

For my goal, I added these settings (like descripted in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537576/how-to-remove-blank-spaces-of-treeview-in-c-sharp-winforms)):

```
        treeView.ShowRootLines = false;
        treeView.ShowLines = false;
        treeView.ShowPlusMinus = false;
        treeView.Indent = 1;
```

And still, there is some empty space left of the treeview.

[image: with Properties false]

How can it be removed?

Edit: Setting the indent to 0 removes the space for the parent nodes succesfully:
[image]

That feels a bit weird because Indent is described as ["distance to indent each child tree node level"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.indent?view=net-5.0). So this approach takes me the possibility to move the child nodes closer to the parent nodes (like in the second image).
So instead of moving just the parent to the left, I'd like to move parent + childs to the left.

Comment: Have you tried settings `DefaultMargin`?

Comment: There is no DefaultMargin property in the treeview and for the form, it is readonly. So I dont know exactly what you mean.

Comment: That's because you have added an ImageList, so it will try to preserve space for the plus/minus glyphs (when you cause the Control's Handle to be recreated). Try to set `treeView.Indent = 0;` Call that code from the Form's constructor, if it's not already there.

Comment: *That feels a bit weird because Indent is described as "distance to indent each child tree node level"*. It also causes side effects. If you want to retain default values, don't set the `Indent` property at all (i.e., remove that line). But you said you wanted the Control *as minimalist as possible*, so that's what `.Indent = 0` does (in this context).

Comment: When I remove it, there is actually no difference so I better  keep it removed. Thanks for your help so far!